# Can't interpret arcs in TopoJSON

Tags: javascript, json, geojson, nvd3.js, topojson

I'm having a lot of problems trying to interpret the arcs member of the TopoJSON as opposed to the coordinates member of the GeoJSON.

Using this reference https://observablehq.com/@syaleni/topojson-vs-geojson

I'm told via the previously lnked reference that this GeoJSON:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Africa"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-6, 36],
            [33, 30],
            [43, 11],
            [51, 12],
            [29, -33],
            [18, -35],
            [7, 5],
            [-17, 14],
            [-6, 36]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Australia"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [143, -11],
            [153, -28],
            [144, -38],
            [131, -31],
            [116, -35],
            [114, -22],
            [136, -12],
            [140, -17],
            [143, -11]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

is the same as this TopoJSON:

```
{
  "type":"Topology",
  "objects": {
    "0": {
      "type":"Polygon",
      "arcs": [
        [
          0
        ]
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name":"Africa"
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "type":"Polygon",
      "arcs": [
        [
          1
        ]
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name":"Australia"
      }
      }
    },
    "arcs": [
      [
        [0,2],[1,0],[0,-1],[0,-1],[-1,0],[0,1],[0,1]
      ],
      [
        [2,1],[0,-1],[0,1]
      ]
    ],
    "bbox": [
      -17,
      -38,
      153,
      36
    ],
    "transform": {
      "scale": [
        85,
        37
      ],
      "translate": [
        -17,
        -38
      ]
    }
}
```

From what "I'm understanding" the arcs are encoded coordinates, the way to get the original cordinates is done with this function:

```
function decodeArc(topology, arc) {
  var x = 0, y = 0;
  return arc.map(function(position) {
    position = position.slice();
    position[0] = (x += position[0]) * topology.transform.scale[0] + topology.transform.translate[0];
    position[1] = (y += position[1]) * topology.transform.scale[1] + topology.transform.translate[1];
    return position;
  });
}
```

Let's say I send the first arc, the first array of points which is `{0,2}`, if I use the function:

```
position[0] = (x += position[0]) * topology.transform.scale[0] + topology.transform.translate[0];
position[1] = (y += position[1]) * topology.transform.scale[1] + topology.transform.translate[1];

position{0} = (0 += 0) * 85 + (-17)
position{1} = (0 += 2) * 37 + (-38)
```

This ends up giving me [-17, 36] which is different of [-6, 36] of the first coordinate on the GeoJSON object.

Tried reading different documentations, even with the official API one on Github and I just can't find the right interpretation for those arcs. ¿Am I doing it wrong? Would appreciate much some advice on this as I've been stuck a day and a half trying to understand these concepts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you change the `quantization` input notice that the figure underneath gets closer to the original Africa & Australia shapes and therefore the topojson in your question is also changing because it is linked to that input. My guess is that if you rework the `decodeArc` logic when `quantization` is around the 40 mark that you might get closer to the original coordinartes you are seeking to reconcile. The author has not been explicit on this point i.e. it is the mechanics of the notebook. If you check the `prequantize` routine in the topojson repo you'll see this `q` parameter is important.